# Handling wildcards in Linux shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I have a directory named "directoryname". If I give the command: `cd direc*` it will go straight into that folder and that's fine. What I want to do is, get the name of the directory from this. As I am running this inside an script, I want to get the full name that the command automatically selected on its own after this operation.

Comment: `pwd` — present working directory.  Also `$PWD`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler `pwd` gives the full path, OP only wants dir-name.

Comment: @shx2: I guess that depends on the interpretation of 'full name'; I assumed it meant the full pathname, but it could mean 'completed name'.  It's easy enough to get the last component: `basename $(pwd)` or `${PWD##*/}` will both do it for most cases (beware the variable mangling if the directory is the root directory).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ foo=(direc*)

$ cd "$foo"

$ echo "$foo"
directoryname
```

[§ Creating Arrays](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays#Creating_Arrays-1)

Comment: This is the answer i was looking for...thnks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you just have one such directory that matches the pattern direc*, you could do the following:

```
cd direc*
mydir=$(basename $(pwd))
echo $mydir
```

Comment: This is the easiest and simplest way of doing that....but Steven Penny's method gives more control over this..